# DataFrame creating weird data structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My code is:

```
for i, out in zip(foo, output):
    # doing stuff and conditions
    # output = each value in col1
    listA.append([i, out])
listA = pd.DataFrame(listA)
```

```
                                                         0  1
0        [15921, 10, 82, 22, 202973, 368, 1055, 3135, 1...  0
1        [609, 226, 413, 363, 211, 241, 988, 80, 12, 19...  0
2        [22572, 3720, 233, 13, 827, 710, 512, 354, 1, ...  0
3                             [345, 656, 25, 2589, 6, 866]  0
4                                [29142, 8, 4141, 456, 24]  0
...                                                    ... ..
1599995                         [256, 8, 80, 110, 25, 152]  4
1599996  [609039, 22, 129, 184, 163, 9419, 769, 358, 10...  4
1599997                       [140, 5715, 6540, 294, 1552]  4
1599998  [59, 22771, 189, 387, 4483, 13, 10305, 112231,...  4
1599999                [59, 15833, 200370, 609041, 609042]  4

[1600000 rows x 2 columns]
```

As you can see, each list has his own length. I want to fill each array to reach `len=118` positions. Is there any way with `DataFrame()` args to do this? Furthermore, it's stacking as 1 column: I want to each value has his own column (i.e., a total of 118 columns + 1 output(`col1`))

Comment: you want to fill this arrays with random numbers?

Comment: @sygneto with `-1` or `NaN` if possible, but I've checked your answer and it works by adding after the loop `df_new.fillna(-1)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input:

```
 data=[
    [[15921, 10, 82, 22, 202973, 368, 1055, 3135]],[[15921, 10, 82, 22, 202973, 368, 1055, 3135]]
    ]
df=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(df)
                                              0
0  [15921, 10, 82, 22, 202973, 368, 1055, 3135]
1  [15921, 10, 82, 22, 202973, 368, 1055, 3135]
```

output, from one column to multiple columns:

```
df_new=pd.DataFrame()

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    a=np.concatenate(row)
    df_new=df_new.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[a]))

print(df_new)

       0   1   2   3       4    5     6     7
0  15921  10  82  22  202973  368  1055  3135
0  15921  10  82  22  202973  368  1055  3135
```

Edit:
**to improve time :**

```
df=df.apply(lambda x : x.explode(),axis=1 )
```

Comment: this works but my dataset has 1.600.000 rows, so it gets a bit slow to reach all of them. s there any faster solution?

Comment: it really worked and faster than the previous solution. Thank you!!